# Retrieving content from external data magnolia

Tags: magnolia

I need to retrieve content for rendering from external data ie. from mgnl-system instead of website workspace. What is the best practice to do that? Is it through the model ie. getContent() method or differently? Is there an example of rendering external content in the codebase?

Answer (score 1):

`mgnl-system` and other `mgnl-` workspaces are internal only and not meant to be shared outside. What would you need them for anyway? There's nothing in there that could be possibly of interest outside.

Comment: Hello Jan. We save a version of the page in mgnl-system temporarily. Under some conditions we would like to render it from there.

Comment: I suggest you use custom workspace for this. The `mgnl-system` workspace is really just "implementation detail" and might disappear from one version to another w/o any upfront notice. Using custom workspace would also allow you to share and access that content from outside easily.

Comment: Hello @Jan. Will do. As for rendering this content from a custom webspace using existing Freemaker templates what approach would you suggest? I tried using a custom AbstractDirective#initContentElement that depending on some conditions overwrites the content parameter. This does not work well for nested content (ie. /content2/5/links/5).

Comment: I would need to have more context and see what exactly you are trying to achieve and where it's failing, but my gut feeling is that when you pass in the content, you need to wrap it and most likely also change few more things in current aggregation state that is passed into FM renderer than just the content element via directive above. You can try to dig into how diff module renders content versions to see what all it has to do to get it rendered but not sure if that would be enough for you or not.